# Check End Date input is 10 months after Start Date input. [PHP]

Tags: php, validation, date, range

Just a student here, limited knowledge and understanding, please bear with me thank you in advance.

I have two inputs, a Start and End datetime input.
I need to see if the End input is after 10 months of Start input.
Ex. if I entered July 7, 2017 the only acceptable input for End is May of 2018 (10 Months after July).

Here is the date format that I used.

```
$start = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['start']));
$end = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['end']));
```

Thank you again, for taking notice.

Answer (score 0):

see http://php.net/manual/zh/datetime.diff.php, you will find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.examples-arithmetic.php) will be useful if you are allowed to accomplish the task with only PHP code. The definition of month is not straightforward. Any professor who asks you to undertake such a problem should be asked to define a month if the definition wasn't given.

If a PHP-only solution is acceptable, the I recommend you remove the mysql tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function:

```
$today = time();
$tenMonthsLater = strtotime("+10 months", $today);
```

and then convert the resulting timestamp to Date and time like this:

```
$dateToday = date('m-d-Y', $today);
$dateAfterTenMonths = date('m-d-Y', $tenMonthsLater);
```

Hope this will help.